# Haskell minigame: check solvability of a maze (updated)

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

```hs
check :: String -> Int -> Int -> IO()
check map len n = do
    let current = searchMap map '@'
    if (flood map current Up len n)
        then printf "\nThis map is solvable. \n"
        else printf "\nThis map is unsolvable. \n"

flood :: String -> Int -> Direction -> Int -> Int -> Bool
flood map current direct len n = do
    let upward = current - n
    let downward = current + n
    let leftward = current - 2
    let rightward = current + 2
    if (current < 0 || current > len || (map !! current) == '*' || (map !! current) == 'x')
        then False
        else if (map !! current) == 't'
            then True
            else do
                case direct of
                    Up -> do
                        let newMap = replaceSign map current "x"
                        (flood map upward Up len n) || (flood map leftward Leftx len n) || (flood map rightward Rightx len n)
                    Down -> do
                        let newMap = replaceSign map current "x"
                        (flood map downward Down len n) || (flood map leftward Leftx len n) || (flood map rightward Rightx len n)
                    Leftx -> do
                        let row = findRow current n 0
                        if current < (row * n)
                            then False
                            else do
                            let newMap = replaceSign map current "x"
                            (flood map upward Up len n) || (flood map downward Down len n) || (flood map leftward Leftx len n)
                    Rightx -> do
                        let row = findRow current n 0
                        if current >= ((row + 1) * n)
                            then False
                            else do
                            let newMap = replaceSign map current "x"
                            (flood map upward Up len n) || (flood map downward Down len n) || (flood map rightward Rightx len n)
```

I am working on a project which needs to make a minigame. The player will need to input a **map**.
Something like this:

```
* * * * * - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - * * * * * 
* * * * * b - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - b * * * * * 
* * * * * - * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * - * * * * * 
* * * * * - * * - - - - * * * * * - - - - * * - * * * * * 
* * * * * - * * - y y - * * * * * - y y - * * - * * * * * 
* * * * * - * * - - - - * * * * * - - - - * * - * * * * * 
* * * * * - * * * * * * - - b - - * * * * * * - * * * * * 
* * * * * - * * * * * * - * * * - * * * * * * - * * * * * 
@ - - - - - * * * * * * - * * * - * * * * * * p - - - - t 
* * * * * - * * * * * * - * * * - * * * * * * - * * * * * 
* * * * * - - - - - - - - * * * - - - - - - - - * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

I struggling in a function to determine whether the map is solvable or not.
In the code, **current** means the current location the program is trying. **len** is the length of the String holding the map. **n** is the length of one line of the map. In the map, **@** means the ball. **-** means roads that the ball can move on. **b** means bonus block (not related to this problem). * means obstacle. **t** means target **p/o/y** means blocks with special use (ball can stop there). My current approach is to use a function **try** to try recursively. The function will turn roads that have already tried into **x** and the function will return **False** if it hit **x**. When function hits obstacles (*) or boundaries of map it will try another two directions. Eg. if you are currently moving **Up**. Then it will try **Leftx** and **Rightx**. If it hits special blocks (**p/o/y**), it will try the other three directions. Eg. if you are currently moving **Rightx**, then it will try **Up**, **Down**, and **Rightx**. However, the program returns "Exception: stack overflow". Is it something wrong with my algorithm? How can I fix this?

Comment: `map` is one dimension list? Why adding and subtracting `n` to `newLoc` when `Up` and `Down` but  `2` to when `Rightx` and `Leftx`?

Comment: What is the smallest map for which your code does not behave the way you want?

Comment: map is one dimension, and for some reason the sample map given to me have one space in between symbols horizontally, but no space between symbols vertically, so I add or subtract 2 to move horizontally. The smallest map size: I haven't tried another map after it failed to do so in the map I shared above

Comment: Btw, I have updated the code with the flood-filling method. But still have the same problem. Still trying to solve it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that once your search has proceeded all the way right and up, so the map looks like this, with the current position the leftmost `-` in the first row:

```
* * * * * - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - * * * * *
* * * * * x - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - b * * * * *
* * * * * x * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * - * * * * *
* * * * * x * * - - - - * * * * * - - - - * * - * * * * *
* * * * * x * * - y y - * * * * * - y y - * * - * * * * *
* * * * * x * * - - - - * * * * * - - - - * * - * * * * *
* * * * * x * * * * * * - - b - - * * * * * * - * * * * *
* * * * * x * * * * * * - * * * - * * * * * * - * * * * *
x x x x x x * * * * * * - * * * - * * * * * * p - - - - t
* * * * * - * * * * * * - * * * - * * * * * * - * * * * *
* * * * * - - - - - - - - * * * - - - - - - - - * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

you enter the following loop with no further `x` marks made  to the map:

```
try map 10 Up ... =
  -- at top row, so we evaluate:
  (try map current Leftx len n) || ...
try map 10 Leftx ... =
  -- star to the left, so we evaluate:
  (try map current Up len n) || ...
try map 10 Up ... =
  -- at top row, so we evaluate:
  (try map current Leftx len n) || ...
-- and we're stuck in an infinite loop
```

The stack eventually overflows because Haskell is keeping track of all those right-hand sides of the `||` operator, though it never gets a chance to try any of them.

I think you'll need to either modify your algorithm to mark walls you've already tried, or maybe switch from working with a single path to [flood filling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) all the non-stars -- if you hit the target while flood fillling, the maze is solvable.

Comment: I have updated my code using the flood-filling method. It still has the stack overflow problem. I am still trying to fix it.